# Can Dollar Store Tool Bench Hardware Wire be baked in oven?

Tags: wire, clay

I recently purchased some 6m wire from the dollar store for a sculpting project.  However, the wire seems to have a sheathing on the outside.  (See pic)

[image]

Is this stuff safe for baking in the oven with my sculpt?

Comment: Why do you want to bake the wire? It is very likely vinyl if you want to look up properties.

Comment: It is being used to reinforce my thicker gauge wire so that my clay will grab on to it better.  However, I found a better wire.   Thanks!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this post](https://www.hfunderground.com/board/index.php?topic=32218.0), the black and red coloured wires are insulated with plastic:

> *2 coils at 33 feet wire red plastic insulation*
> *2 coils at 33 feet wire black plastic insulation*

Unless you find packages with the regular 'silver' coloured wire - which according to a review [here](https://www.dollartree.com/tool-bench-wire-set-4pc/281345) might actually be hard - I suggest using different wires.

Comment: Plus 22 gauge wire is pretty lightweight for an armature.

Comment: You could also strip it off with a standard wire stripper, but that can be a pain in the butt -- and if you have to buy a new tool, it's cheaper to just get new wire :)

Answer (score 1):

If you are making an armature , a good hardware store will have several sizes of bare copper wire . Mostly larger diameters like 12 gauge up to 000 ( guessing 0.312")

Comment: This is helpful for future projects, but doesn't answer the specific question about whether this wire can be safely baked.